# Limiting refresh rate at 60 FPS of SurfaceView on new Android devices with high refresh rates (90-120Hz)

Tags: android, surfaceview, frame-rate, glsurfaceview

I'm facing increased and even doubled FPS on new Android devices with 90Hz and 120Hz screens (e.g. Samsung S20 FE), it affects my game, which I've developed based on `GLSurfaceView` (OpenGL implementation of `SurfaceView`). Originally it was always running at 60 frames per seconds maximum, but now it seems to go all the way up to the 90 and even 120 FPS on some new Android devices, which makes the game unplayable. What could be the best and reliable solution to limit or cap the screen refresh rate at 60Hz max?

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/frame-rate

Comment: @MorrisonChang - Yes I've read the documentation, however the solution it offers is not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll use it unless someone recommends a simpler and tested solution.

Comment: Just FYI: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/04/high-refresh-rate-rendering-on-android.html and [From Systrace to Safetynet: Android Game Development Case Studies (Google I/O'19) youtube video](https://youtu.be/1xTl9o_agGc)

Comment: @MorrisonChang - Thank you, very much appreciated!